# Screen recording on Pi running Kali-Linux

Tags: pi-3, arm, kali

is there any way to screen record what I am doing on my RaspberryPi3 running Kali linux? , I have used RecordMyDesktop, Kazam, Vokoscreen none of them work properly.. Maybe it has something to do with the ARM processor..

RecordMydesktop is the only one that works but it shows me the recording in pink .. I have no idea why and I didnt mess with the configurations, the other ones just dont work or get stuck in the middle of the recording..

Any suggestions? desperate here.

Comment: It's odd that vokoscreen is not working on Kali, because it works like a charm right out of the box on Raspbian. So it's definitely not about the ARM CPU.

Answer (score 1):

I have an external in line game capture box that interfaces into the hdmi. It just records what output is sent to the screen.